# One-dimensional tight-binding model with two different hoppings in the limit the hoppings are equal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I've recently been watching [this lecture series](https://pirsa.org/C22002) on Condensed Matter. The part I'm currently on covers band theory for the tight-binding model in a few different scenarios. We covered two different models in one-dimension. The first had a Hamiltonian given by
$$H = -t \sum_i c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} + c_{i+1}^\dagger c_i,$$
where the sum runs over the $N$ sites in the one-dimensional chain with periodic boundary conditions and $c_i$ is a creation operator for an orbital at site $i$. We solved this model and got to the single-particle eigenenergies
$$E(k) = - 2 t \cos(k a),$$
where $a$ is the lattice spacing and $k = \frac{2\pi n}{N a}$, with $n = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1$.

The second model had two sites per unit cell. We have $N$ unit cells and have the Hamiltonian
$$H = - \sum_i t_1(c_{i,A}^\dagger c_{i,B} + c_{i,B}^\dagger c_{i,A}) + t_2(c_{i-1,B}^\dagger c_{i,A} + c_{i+1,A}^\dagger c_{i,B}),$$
where $A$ and $B$ label the two different sites per unit cell. The single-particle eigenenergies we found this time were
$$E(k) = \pm \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2 + 2 t_1 t_2 \cos(ka)},$$
where $a$ is the size of one unit cell and $k = \frac{2\pi n}{N a}$, $n = 0,1, \ldots, N_1$ (to the best of my knowledge).

What I find weird is that I would expect that the limit $t_1 \to t_2$ in the second model should reduce it to the first model with $t = t_1 = t_2$, albeit with $2N$ sites instead of $N$. However, that is not what happens, since the second model always has two energy bands, while the first has only one. My question is: why doesn't the second model reduce to the first one in the limit $t_1 \to t_2$?

Comment: Do the Hamiltonians converge to the same Hamiltonian?

Comment: For me the second Hamiltonian has a completely different interpretation than the first, so I wouldn't expect both results to coincide even for $t_1=t_2$. I think this is along the lines what @Mauricio wants to point to (?).

Comment: How is your second Hamiltonian hermitian at all? The second term looks weird...

Comment: @TobiasFünke using the periodic boundary conditions, one can relabel $i\to i-1$ and get $\sum_i c_{i+1,A}^\dagger c_{i,B} = \sum_i c_{i,A}^\dagger c_{i-1,B}$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that, sorry. Just a minor (unrelated) additional comment: The energies $E(k)$ you give are the single-particle energies; the eigenvalues of $H$, an operator defined on the Fock space, are of the form $\sum_{k} E(k) n_k$, where the $n_k$ are the occupation numbers.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Oops, you're right. I just updated the post to make this explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way in which we can make sense of the limits in a physical situation in which the limit $t_1\to t_2$ should yield the first Hamiltonian.  We could think of the atomic species as being the same, but there being two different crystal structures.  The first is one in which every atom is a distance $a$ apart.  In the second, we shift every *other* atom some small distance $\alpha a$ to the right, with $\alpha < 1$.  This would then introduce alternating hopping strengths due to the differing distances between adjacent atoms, but in the limit as we take $\alpha \to 0$, this becomes the original lattice.  The lattices are illustrated below.

[image]

Crucially, we have *doubled* the size of the unit cell from $a$ to $2a$.  This makes it so that in the *second* dispersion relation, we should take $a\to 2a$, yielding
$$
E(k) = \pm \sqrt{t^2 + t_2^2 + 2 t t_2 \cos(2ka)}\,,
$$
where I have set $t_1=t$. In the limit as $t_2\to t$, the above becomes
$$
E(k) \to \pm 2t \cos(ka)\,.
$$
It *seems* like this is a problem, because we get two branches (the plus and the minus).  However, we haven't taken into account the fact that the first Brillouin zone must *double in size* in this degenerate limit, because the size of the unit cell gets cut in *half* ($2a\to a$) in this limit. Thus, we need to "unfold" the dispersion relation out of the reduced zone scheme picture we needed in going from a unit cell of size $a$ to a unit cell of size $2a$.

This is illustrated below.  The black dashed curve is the dispersion relation for the simple case of the crystal structure with equal inter-atomic spacings $a$.  The solid black curve is the dispersion relation for the diatomic lattice with $t_2/t = 1.3$.  The dashed black curve is the dispersion relation for the *mono*atomic lattice, and we plot it over a larger region because the Brillouin zone is twice as large!  Then, we can see that the positive branch of the limit dispersion relation (i.e., $+2t\cos(ka)$) seems as if it's a second branch of the dispersion relation, but really we need to shift those over by reciprocal lattice vectors (of the diatomic lattice) to where they *should* be in the first Brillouin zone of the monatomic lattice.

[image]

Thus, we *can* take the limit and get the same system, but you need to make sure that the unit cell sizes are consistent and that you are thinking carefully about the actual periodicity of your system and hence the correct size of the first Brillouin zone.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your second equation an setting $t_1,t_2\to t$, we get
$$E(k)=\pm t \sqrt2 \sqrt{1+\cos(ka)}=\pm 2 t \cos\left(\frac{ka}2\right)$$

where I used $1+\cos x = 2 \cos x/2$. The $k/2$ comes because $N$ is different by a factor of 2.

However notice that there is still a $\pm$. This happens because the equation used is not right, it was diagonalized as if I was handling a two-species unit cell, so we get a duplication of the bands.

Comment: Yes, but you still have the $\pm$-"problem" (i.e. you have two bands, which are non-degenerate, except at the BZ boundary, even if you have $t_1=t_2$). The point is, I guess, that the second model simply has two species (or two sites per unit cell), so it is fundamentally different from the first one to start with, no?

Comment: In that limit, you have chosen a non-primitive unit cell. The number of bands in your system is determined by the degrees of freedom in the unit cell, so if you chose a unit cell with four of the same orbitals, you would get four bands in a Brillouin zone which is four times smaller. The relevant keywords for this are band folding and extended zone schemes.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasFünke for noticing, indeed it is dependent on how the diagonalization was done.

Comment: I still don't understand the $\pm$ "issue". The eigenvalues of an operator do not depend on the procedure I use to diagonalize it, so why does it matter in this case?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves when you are diagonalizing you are still treating the Hamiltonian as a two species lattice, setting $t_i\to t$ does not solve this issue. You should first set $t_i\to t/2 $ and then diagonalize you will then recover the same result.

Comment: @Mauricio I still don't see the problem. It seems to me that setting $t_i \to t/2$ would still leave two bands, and I can't see how my choice of using a non-primitive unit cell could change the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves The point is that in the second you have two species $A,B$. Why do you think both Hamiltonians would have the same spectrum (and possible degeneracies) (regardless what you choose for $t_1$ and $t_2$). To start, consider e.g. the dimensions of the underlying Hilbert spaces...Try also to see what happens if you put (formally) $A=B$...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Perhaps it is because I'm a beginner in Condensed Matter physics (I'm actually a relativist checking another area), but I don't see how the two species lead to something different. It seems to me that I'm just choosing to use the labels $(0,A), (0,B), (1,A), (1,B), \ldots$ instead of $0,1,2,3,\ldots$. To me it seems merely a difference in notation

Comment: Here is my understanding from a more general POV: In the first scenario you have a $N$-dimensional single-particle Hilbert space; in the second scenario, however, you have  for each $i$ two further internal degrees of freedom, labeled by $A$ and $B$. This immediately doubles the dimension of your single-particle Hilbert space (and hence the dimension of the Fock space changes from $2^N$ to $2^{2N}$). That immediately shows you that any Hamiltonian of the second scenario needs more eigenvalues; and if it is non-trivial, then it leads to different eigenvalues.

Comment: ...and as I tried to put now in several comments: The Hamiltonian in the second case really looks different! For example, you don't have tunneling of the same species between different sites. I think you should rather study the case where $A=B$, and then check how both Hamiltonians, then defined on the same Hilbert space, differ.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves would a plot help? I can make it later, meanwhile try to plot it for different values of $t$ see how it folds/unfolds.

Comment: @Mauricio I don't think so. I tried plotting the energies on Desmos and I see that the two bands of the second Hamiltonian overlap with the single band of the first Hamiltonian (once one resolves the $2N$ detail), but they still have "extra" energy values

Comment: Here's my plot: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/if7jwfjvh2

Comment: @NíckolasAlves march beat me to it, but I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, it is =). Thank you very much for your help!